# Unsupported protocol: t3 exception while trying to get number of threads in weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic, rmi, jmx

I am using JMX to get number of threads in Weblogic but an error happens. 
This is my code:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameTitlePane.MaximizeAction;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class JMXClient {
         private static MBeanServerConnection connection;
         private static JMXConnector connector;
         private static ObjectName service;
    //Update correct port
    private static String port = "7001";
    //Update localhost if server is accessed remotely   
        private static String url = "t3://localhost:7001";
    // Update hostname if server is accessed remotely
        private static String hostname = "localhost";

        private static String username = "weblogic";
         private static String password = "12345678";
    // server name can differ from host name
    private static String serverName = "AdminServer";
         /*
         * Initialize connection to the Runtime MBean Server
         */
        private static void init() throws IOException, MalformedURLException {
            String protocol = "t3";
            Integer portInteger = Integer.valueOf(port);
            int port = portInteger.intValue();
            String jndiroot = "/jndi/";
            String mserver = "weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime";
            //JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(url);
            JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(protocol, hostname, port, jndiroot + mserver);
            Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
            env.put(JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "weblogic.management.runtime.JRockitRuntimeMBean");
            connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, env);
            connection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
             try {
                             service = new ObjectName("com.bea:Name="+serverName + ",Type=ServerRuntime");
        } catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
        public static void getTotalNumberOfThreads() {
            try {
                init();
                Long totalNumberOfThreads = (Long) connection.getAttribute(service,"TotalNumberOfThreads");
                System.out.println("totalNumberOfThreads is: " + totalNumberOfThreads);
                connection.invoke(service, "start", new Object[] {}, new String[] {});
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }             
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Invoke required methods
                   JMXClient.getTotalNumberOfThreads();
            }
}
```

The error is :

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: Unsupported protocol: t3
at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.newJMXConnector(Unknown Source)
at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(Unknown Source)
```

I don't know why this happens. 
When I am using `weblogic.management.remote` to get the state of application server, everything is ok, but for the number of threads, it doesn't answer.

Comment: I am thinking this one might just be a classpath issue. Make sure you have both wljmxclient.jar and wlclient.jar on your classpath

Comment: @castling I have added these two jars but the exception is still alive

Answer (score 1):

I put all these five jars in classpath to solved similar issue:

```
    <include name="wlclient.jar" />
    <include name="wljmsclient.jar" />
    <include name="wls-api.jar"/>
    <include name="wljmxclient.jar"/>
    <include name="wlconnector.jar"/>
```

Comment: In fact, if you add `wljmxclient` only it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need the following jars only:
\Oracle_Home\wlserver\server\lib\wljmxclient.jar
\Oracle_Home\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.jar

it works with me against default and sql provider.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue in WLS12.2.1.3, fixed after adding only the /wlserver/server/lib/wlthint3client.jar file to the libraries.